# Neumann problem for exterior of circle .(Drichlet)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-physics

find the equation for outer side of circle using Neumann method.

$\Delta u= F(r,\varphi),$

$ 0<r_0<r, $

$0\leq \varphi<2\pi,$

$u_{r}(r_0,\varphi = f(\varphi), \left| u \right|<\infty),$

if,

$ F= \frac{A\ln r}{r^3}\times \cos2\varphi$

solution:

$\Delta u= \frac{A\ln r}{r^3} \times \cos 2\varphi $

$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} r \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x^2} =\frac{A\ln r}{r^3}\times\cos2\varphi $

$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r }{\partial x} \frac{\partial u }{\partial x} = \frac{A\ln r}{r^3}\times\cos2\varphi $

let,

$u(r,\varphi)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$

$R''\Theta+\frac{1}{r}R'\Theta+\frac{1}{r^2}R\Theta''=0;$

$r^2R''+rR'-\lambda R=0..............................(1)$

$\Theta''+\lambda\Theta=0...........................................(2)$

I used cases for $\lambda$:

1. $\lambda < 0 $

say,

$ \lambda = -\mu ^2( \mu > 0)$

so

$\Theta '' - \mu ^2\Theta = 0$

$\Theta(\theta)=C_1 e^{\mu \theta} + C_2 e^{-\mu \theta},$

since $\theta $ is periodic $C_1=C_2=0$

for case 2:

$\lambda=0; \Theta ''=0$

$\Theta(\theta)=A\theta+B$

since $\theta $ is periodic $A=0$, $\Theta(\theta)= B $ or just 1

$\lambda = 0$

$r^2R''+rR'=0$

using Eular theorem,

$s(s-1)+s=0$

$s^2=0$

$s=0,0$

$R(r)=C_1r^0+C_2r^0\ln r= C_1+C_2\ln r$

for $r\rightarrow 0$,

$u(r,\theta)= R(r)\Theta(\theta)=1$

case 3:

$\lambda>0$

say $\lambda = \mu ^2 (\mu>0)$

so i found $\Theta(\theta) = C_1\cos(\mu \theta)+C_2\sin(\mu \theta)$

with euler theorem

$r^2R''+rR'-n^2R=0$

$s(s-1)+s-n^2=0$

$s=\pm n$

$R(r)=C_1r^n+C_2r^{-n}$

if r\rightarrow 0, C_2=0;

$R(r)= C_1r^n = Ar^n$

thus $u(r,\theta)= Ar^n(C_1cos(n\theta)- C_2sin(n\theta))$

now i don't know how to do it.

please can anyone complete it for me.

Comment: Try $R=r^\alpha$ and find $\alpha$. You should recognize a familiar ODE for $\Theta$.

Comment: I used cases for $\lambda$:

Comment: You can find $\lambda$ directly, based on the fact that $\Theta$ must be periodic with period $2\pi$.